# conditionnally extract values from a nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array, nested

How could I extract a list of values out of a nested array; matching a condition ?

```
const tree = {
   "menu_id":"root",
   "open":true,
   "items":[
      {
        "menu_id":"Brussels",
        "open":false,
         "items":[
            {
               "menu_id":"Brussels/CBD",
               "open":true,
               "items":[
                  {
                     "menu_id":"Brussels/CBD/Centre",
                     "open":false
                  },
                  {
                     "menu_id":"Brussels/CBD/Louise",
                     "open":true
                  },
                  {
                     "menu_id":"Brussels/CBD/Léopold",
                     "open":false
                  },
                  {
                     "menu_id":"Brussels/CBD/Midi",
                     "open":true
                  },
                  {
                     "menu_id":"Brussels/CBD/North",
                     "open":false
                  }
               ]
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like to get a list of menu_id values, where the open attribute is false, that would thus give:

```
var closed = ['Brussels','Brussels/CBD/Centre','Brussels/CBD/Léopold','Brussels/CBD/North']
```

How could I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: so ignore that `"menu_id":"root",
   "open":true,`

Comment: @mplungjan: While this question perhaps doesn't show enough effort, your suggested duplicate is quite different.  This one is looking for a way to collect all matching nodes into an array, regardless of depth.  That one keeps the tree structure intact, keeping only the matching leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1):

One useful way to write this is to build a generic function that handles trees of all sorts and arbitrary predicates, and then build your function atop that.

This version does that and then partially applies a function describing the tree structure to get a new function, partially applies a predicate to that to get another function which accepts a tree and returns all nodes that match the predicate.  Finally, our main function accepts a tree, calls the previous function and extracts the id node from each result.

```js
const filterDeep = (getKids) => (pred) => (tree) => [
  ... (pred (tree) ? [tree] : []),
  ... (getKids (tree)) .flatMap (filterDeep (getKids) (pred))
]

const filterItems = 
  filterDeep (({items = []}) => items)

const closed =
  filterItems (({open}) => !open)

const closedIds = (tree) =>
  closed (tree) .map (({menu_id}) => menu_id)

const tree = {menu_id: "root", open: true, items: [{menu_id: "Brussels", open: false, items: [{menu_id: "Brussels/CBD", open: true, items: [{menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Centre", open: false}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Louise", open: true}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Léopold", open: false}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Midi", open: true}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/North", open: false}]}]}]}

console .log (closedIds (tree))
```

We could obviously write `closedIds` directly atop `filterDeep`, with something like this:

```js
const closedIds = (tree) =>
  filterDeep (({items}) => items) (({open}) => open == false) (tree) 
    .map (({menu_id}) => menu_id)
```

and, while there's nothing precisely wrong with that, those intermediate functions are possibly reusable, and I think help make the problem more clear.  For instance, `filterItems` is a function that takes a predicate and a tree where the children of a node are in an array called `items` and returns all the nodes (at whatever level of nesting) matching the predicate.  It seems pretty useful.

---

However, if you just want a dedicated function, we can merge all that down into something fairly simple:

```js
const closedIds = (tree) => [
  ... (tree.open ? [] : [tree.menu_id]),
  ... (tree.items || []) .flatMap (closedIds)
]

const tree = {menu_id: "root", open: true, items: [{menu_id: "Brussels", open: false, items: [{menu_id: "Brussels/CBD", open: true, items: [{menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Centre", open: false}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Louise", open: true}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Léopold", open: false}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/Midi", open: true}, {menu_id: "Brussels/CBD/North", open: false}]}]}]}

console .log (closedIds (tree))
```

Comment: another use case for `filterDeep` :D

Comment: @Thankyou: I'm still not sure about the name.  There are two different styles of deep filtering I use.  One creates an array of matches; the other keeps the tree structure but reduces the number of nodes.  Neither seems more deserving than the other to get the name `filterDeep`, but calling one `deepFilter` and the other `filterDeep` is too confusing.

Comment: for pruning trees but keeping shape i have used names `prune` or `shake`

Comment: @Thankyou: `prune` sounds good to me.  I'll keep `deepFilter` for this.

Comment: i should clarify, `prune` returns the tree without the "filtered" bits, whereas `shake` returns the "filtered" bits. nothing wrong with `deepFilter` though  ^^

Comment: @Thankyou: Yes, I don't particularly like `shake` as a name, but `prune` is crystal-clear.  When we wanted an opposite-sense of `filter` in Ramda, we were somewhat happy with `reject`.  But for a tree, `prune` seems clear enough, and I don't (yet) have anything better than `shake` for its complement, but will keep looking.